# How do I make a file that identifies as a custom UTI type?

Tags: objective-c, macos, uti

Right now I have an application that generates an XML file. We'll call it someFile.myapp
When my app saves the file and look at it using mdls it has a kMDItemContentType of "dyn.234kdfsjk23jk24234kjfd"
How can I get the UTI type of the file to be a custom value like com.mycompany.myapp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTIs are linked to extensions via a declaration in your application's `Info.plist` file. Add a section like so:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Special File Type</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>org.myapp.someutiidentifier</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: I was having a hell of a time getting my custom file type to be saved along with the file in my document-based app. UTTypeConformsTo was the key. After 5 hours I still have no idea where "public.xml" comes from, as I can't find it documented anywhere, but I'm just happy that it works. Am I the only one who thinks Apple UTIs are [aptly named](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_tract_infection)?

Comment: Yeah, it's not well-documented; you have to grab definitions here and there, though 'public.xml' is a famous one.

The canonical reference (as in Read The Source, Luke) is `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` .

Answer (score 1):

Dream up a unique extension for your file, and use an exported UTI declaration to associate the extension with your UTI.

Answer (score 1):

Files are mapped to UTIs by Launch Services, which is theoretically able to use many different kinds of information about the file to identify its type, but in practice will disregard everything other than the file extension. Consequently, if you want your file's type to be identifiable, you need to come up with a unique extension and map it to the relevant type in your app's Info.plist. If your files need to share an extension that has already been claimed by another app, then you're SOL.

As far as I can see -- and I say this as a longtime Mac fan -- this is the one aspect of Mac OS X where it is really apt to say: "Welcome to 1985!"